# Restrict date time in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the datetime picker from this site: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker which works fine.

Here we can set the minDate and Max Date like this:

```
    $(".timepic").datetimepicker({
        minDate:'2014-05-03',
        maxDate: '2014-05-04',  
    });
```

I'm trying to implement the same with date time say:

```
    $(".timepic").datetimepicker({
        minDate:'2014-05-03 12:15:04',
        maxDate: '2014-05-04 15:15:25',  
    });
```

so that the user cannot pick the time beyond and below the mentioned limit. Had any one has got the same problem?

Comment: v4 (recently released) is much better at restricting time in the min/max dates now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".timepic").datetimepicker()
$(".timepic").data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(new Date("May 03, 2014"));
$(".timepic").data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(new Date("May 04, 2014"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding latest versions of bootstrap(above v3.1.3)  try this :

```
$(".timepic").datetimepicker();

$(".timepic").data("DateTimePicker")
             .minDate(new Date("May 03, 2014"));

$(".timepic").data("DateTimePicker")
             .maxDate(new Date("May 04, 2014"));
```